# JS clickEvent target on Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to find how a clickEvent object be triggered. Here is the Codepen link

https://codepen.io/rpmcmurphy/pen/WNegvQd?editors=1011

Here, when I click on the dropdown items, clickEvent is fired but when the button is clicked, it doesn't. There is not much documentation I could find what a clickEvent is and how can it be triggered.

Here is the code-

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn mt-5 ml-5 dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <button class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>


<button class="btn mt-2 ml-5 ola">Ola</button>
```

JS

```
 $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
  console.log(e.clickEvent.target);
});

$('.ola').on('click', function(e) {
   console.log(e.clickEvent.target);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove clickEvent from your logs and use "e.target" only

Comment: @Viana Thanks. By the way, could you please point out why it's not accessible in the second case and how to generate clickEvent object on it? Or any documentation around for better understanding clickEvent? That would  be helpful.

Comment: the parameter "e" is the click event, it returns an object with several properties, and the property "clickEvent" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

The click event is being fired. It's just that the object you receive in your function for `.ola` is not the same as your other function.

If you need to access the element directly you could instead write

```
$('.ola').on('click', function(e) {
   console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

For future reference, if you see errors in your console it often helps to look at the whole object instead of just its properties.

E.g.

```
$('.ola').on('click', function(e) {
   console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wanted to understand the clickEvent part of the question more a bit. How is that object generated and how to access that. Like why it's accessible in the first case and not getting in the second case. Is there any specific documentation available on this? I couldn't fine any.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/on/

It's a bit of a meaty read but the answer lies in defineing `namespaces`.

When you define namespaces you make it possible to add multiple handlers onto a single event. In the Bootstrap library `'hide.bs.dropdown'` is defined to have a clickEventHandler whereas `'click'` is just the basic jQuery click handler.

Comment: So, basically clickEvent is an event handler provided by Bootstrap if I understand correctly?

Comment: Bootstrap defines a name space `'hide.bs.dropdown'` to have a `clickEvent` handler using `jQuery`. The generic 'click' jQuery handler does not have `clickEvent` defined because that's redundant.